# How to denote enumerating 1, 2, ..., n?

Tags: notation

What is the best way to denote it?

1. $\forall i\in\{1,\dots,n\}: P(i)$;

   $\forall i=1,\dots,n: P(i)$;

   $\forall i=\overline{1,n}: P(i)$;

   $P(i)$ for $i=1,\dots,n$;

   ...

Comment: I find it strange that there is no uniform notation for this common set. Another notation I have seen is $\underline{n}$.

Comment: I have also seen $[1,n]$ on this site and $[n]$ elsewhere.

Comment: Dem'yanov & Malozemov use $[1:n]$ in "Introduction to minimax".

Comment: I use $(\forall i\in \mathbb{N}_n)(P(i))$. However in your notations, 1 and 4 are the best. 2,3 are not acceptable.

Comment: $ i \gets $ _enumerate_ $ ([1, n]) $, and then let's invent a new math symbol for _enumberate_.

Answer (score 11):

Use "$P(i)$ for $i=1,...,n$" to refer to the property being true in those cases. Using existential and universal quantifiers in ordinary mathematical prose (as opposed to formal logic text) is ugly.

Comment: Some mathematicians disagree with excluding quantifies. However there are theorems about logic of quantifiers and some definitions include a long combination of quantifiers (they are frequent in analysis).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I've ever seen the notation $\overline{1, n}$, so *I* wouldn't use that :)  But, maybe others know it, so maybe it's okay.  Other than that, I wouldn't use $\forall$ or $:$ ever and most of my experience with such notation is in the class where you first learn it.  I would use words but the basic forms of your 1, 2, and 4 seem pretty good.

$P(i)$ is true for all $i$ such that $1 \leq i \leq n$.

$P(i)$ is true for $i = 1, \ldots, n$.

For $i = 1, \ldots, n$, $P(i)$ is true.